# Can I make a file that opens a .mp4 and a few other bash scripts at the same time?

Tags: bash

I want to make a .sh file that opens a music video, minimizes the videos window, and opens 3 new terminals with commands running in each of them. So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Videos
mplayer (videoname).mp4 & bg &
gnome-terminal -x cd & cd (program directory) & (command)
gnome-terminal -x cd & cd (program directory) & (command)
gnome-terminal -x cd & cd (program directory) & (command)
```

The terminals keep saying child something and the video window isn't minimized.
Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the problems with your script (so far)

```
    mplayer videoname.mp4 & bg &
```

1. The `bg &` is unnecessary because the `&` in `mplayer videoname.mp4 &` runs the command.
2. The `bg &` is meaningless anyway.  The `bg` command says to run the most recently **interactively stopped** subprocess for the script in the background.  There can't be any interactively stopped subprocesses ... since this is script.  And running `bg` as a in the background is doubly meaningless.
3. You seem to think that running in the background and minimizing are the same thing.  They are not.

   Forcibly minimizing a window from a script is a bit tricky; see https://askubuntu.com/questions/4876/can-i-minimize-a-window-from-the-command-line/904558#904558

Then this:

```
    gnome-terminal -x cd & cd (program directory) & (command)
```

That looks so garbled it is hard to make out what you are actually trying to do.  But I suspect you are trying to run a terminal in which you run `cd somedir; somecmd`.  Doing that requires a subshell; e.g. something like this

```
    gnome-terminal -e '/bin/sh -c "cd somedir; somecmd"' &
```

Note that the correct placements of the quotes in the above is critical.

Comment: Ah, I remember asking this when I first started programming. I wanted to make a song play and open three terminals doing something at startup because I thought it would be cool. 1337 Hax0r style, hah. Thank you for taking the time to answer, though.